# Opening a PDF from $http.post crash when using _blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a post to a WS and receive a PDF, I transform it into a blob, create a URL and open it.

If i'm opening the pdf in '_self', it works! I see the pdf.
I can also create a link with a download element and it works too!
But if i'm opening the pdf in '_blank', a new tab is created and instantly close.

Here is my code:

```
getDoc(id) {
  const url = 'url';
  this.$http.post(
    url,
    {
      data: {
        id,
      },
    },
    {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    }).then((response) => {
      const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf;' });
      const urlPdf = this.$window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const win = this.$window.open(urlPdf, '_blank');
      win.focus();
    });
}
```

Do I have to add something to allow it to open in a new tab/window?

Why does it works for _self but not _blank?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you don't have some ad/popup blockers - I had a similar issue

Comment: Oh wow adblock was closing it! You were right! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you! <3

Comment: Please self-answer this, as I didn't really solved anything, it was just a recommendation :) Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had adblock enabled and this was the problem, once disabled the pdf is now working with _blank!

Thanks Alon Eitan for your comment!